# For which value of $b$ the function $f(x)=b \sin(x)-x$ is one-one?

Tags: analysis

I draw the graphs and the correct answer is $[0,1]$ the domain of $b$ for which $f$ is one-one. But i don't know how to prove this. Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs to be monotonic, meaning that the derivative shouldn't change sign.

$$f'(x)=b\cos x-1\leq 0$$
$$b\cos x \leq 1$$
Because $|\cos x|\leq 1$, you need $b\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: The function needs to be _strictly_ monotonic, which means that the derivative shouldn't change sign, and also that the derivative is non-zero except at isolated points.